# In which representation are monopoles of grand unifying theories classified?

Tags: field-theory, group-representations, magnetic-monopoles, solitons, grand-unification

In the context of grand unification theories A.Zee's book states that $SU(5)$ (or $SO(10)$ if $SU(5)$ is considered as outdated as GUT candidate) as GUT and as spontaneously broken non-abelian gauge theory contains the monopole. I am wondering in which representation of $SU(5)$ it should be classified,  may be as a singlet? Or is this question not meaningful since the monopole is perhaps a soliton? So if it were a soliton, how would it be classified?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Monopoles are somewhat subtle, and there are different layers towards their classification, each being more correct than the previous one.

<sup>Quick remark: what is usually called the $\text{SO}(10)$ model should more properly be called the $\text{Spin}(10)$ model, because it contains spinors. One has $\pi_1\text{Spin}(n)=0$ and $\text{Spin}(2n)^\vee=\text{PSO}(2n)$ and $\text{Spin}(2n+1)^\vee=\text{PSp}(2n)$. Also, one should point out that the correct GUT embedding reads $\text{SU}(3)\times \text{SU}(2)\times \text U(1)/\mathbb Z_6\hookrightarrow \text{SU}(5)$ and so, strictly speaking, the formulas below only make sense for $n=6$.</sup>

### The ABC of magnetic monopoles.

1. **Goddard-Nuyts-Olive**: the monopoles of a gauge theory with gauge group $G$ are classified by the representations of the GNO/Langlands dual group $G^\vee$ (cf. Ref. 1). For example, the dual of $\text{SU}(N)$ is $\text{PSU}(N)$, whose representations are basically the adjoint and its tensor powers. Similarly, the dual of $\text{SO}(2n)$ is $\text{SO}(2n)$ itself, and that of $\text{SO}(2n+1)$ is $\text{Sp}(2n)$. The representations of these are all well-known.
2. **Lubkin**: the GNO monopoles are typically unstable unless there is some topological charge that protects them. This topological charge takes values in $\pi_1G$  (cf. Ref. 2), and so one may have non-trivial monopoles if and only if $G$ is not simply-connected. For $\text{SU}(N)$ one has $\pi_1=0$ and so there are no monopoles. On the other hand, $\pi_1 \text{SO}(n)=\mathbb Z_2$, so here one does expect a (unique) non-trivial monopole.
3. **The SSB monopole**: if the theory undergoes a Higgs mechanism $G\to H$ one has slightly more freedom in making stable monopoles (cf. Refs. 3,4). In particular, these are classified not by $\pi_1G$ or $\pi_1H$ but by $\pi_2(G/H)=\operatorname{ker}(\pi_1 H\to\pi_1 G)$. For example, if $G$ is simply-connected one has $\operatorname{ker}(\pi_1 H\to\pi_1 G)=\pi_1H$ and so the classification reduces to that of Lubkin. Indeed, if
   $$
   \text{SU}(5)\to \text{SU}(3)\times \text{SU}(2)\times \text U(1)/\mathbb Z_n,\qquad n\in\{1,2,3,6\}
   $$
   one has a
   $$
   \operatorname{ker}(\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z_n\to 0)=\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z_n
   $$
   classification. Similarly, for an $\text{SO}(10)$ model one has a
   $$
   \operatorname{ker}(\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z_n\to \mathbb Z_2)=\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z_{\lceil n/2\rceil}
   $$
   classification (this last equality is an educated guess; ask your friend the mathematician to be sure).

**References.**

1. [Gauge theories and magnetic charge](https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(77)90221-8), P.Goddard, J.Nuyts, D.Olive.
2. [Geometric definition of gauge invariance](https://doi.org/10.1016/0003-4916(63)90194-5), Elihu Lubkin.
3. [Magnetic monopoles in unified gauge theories](https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(74)90486-6), G.'t Hooft.
4. [Particle Spectrum in the Quantum Field Theory](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/#abs/1974JETPL..20..194P/abstract), Alexander M. Polyakov.

Comment: WoW !! I had never thought, that it is so complicated. Thank you very much, that is much more than I expected. Just a little question : What does the index $1$ res. $2$ at the representation sign $\pi_{1/2}$, which representation is it ?

Comment: @FredericThomas $\pi_i G$ refers to the $i$th [homotopy group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_group). In short, $\pi_0 G$ is the number of connected components of $G$; $\pi_1G$ counts the number of one-dimensional holes in $G$; and $\pi_2$ counts the number of two-dimensional holes in $G$.

Comment: Thank you very much!